# Expo cannot update npm packages due to SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, ssl-certificate, expo

Expo for React Native requires the dependency for react-native to be formatted like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz"
}
```

When I use `npm install` to update node packages, I get the following error

```
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

This only happens in my expo projects. I can use npm install without any self signed certificate issues in other node projects.

How can I remove the self signed certificate? Otherwise how can I solve this error without disabling SSL completely?

I have already tried `npm config set ca ""` as well as upgrading npm to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

try this.
the only solution

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: This worked for me on Windows.