# npm request failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying to run Expo react-native project from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

```
npm install expo -g
expo init AwesomeProject
npm start
```

But on running npm start i am getting this error

> npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
>   npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
>   npm ERR! request to https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

i tried the following commands as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141153/nodejs-npm-err-code-self-signed-cert-in-chain)

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But it didnt help. I dont want to disable strict SSL. As stated.Can someone suggest?

Comment: No actually. You realised my pain. So cool to see people taking efforts to share google search query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs "npm ERR! code SELF\_SIGNED\_CERT\_IN\_CHAIN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141153/nodejs-npm-err-code-self-signed-cert-in-chain)

Comment: I have mentioned that link in the post. and no

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the expo repo on github. ill raise a issue on the github in sometime.

Comment: With 2400 answers, it was a reasonable idea that perhaps there was something out there. Just trying to help...

Comment: I am not the other type of user which you are trying to project here. But lets focus on the solution . can we?

Comment: Seems you are not the only one not getting answers either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695693/expo-cannot-update-npm-packages-due-to-self-signed-cert-in-chain

Comment: This seems more promising, [From the expo forum](https://forums.expo.io/t/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain/2463)

Answer (score 0):

Set in command prompt or terminal (mac OS)

`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

then, install your packages or `npm install`